# how to get getPooledConnection() on MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource

Tags: junit, junit4

I have a class where i want the pool connection . I created `MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource` object and on that i'm calling the `getPooledConnection()` method like this

```
MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource datasource;
PooledConnection pconn=null;
pconn = dataSource.getPooledConnection();
```

when i am run the test class i am unable to get ant thing in 
`pconn = dataSource.getPooledConnection();` That is `dataSource.getPooledConnection()` returning nothing. How to fix this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource` in a test and not a Java EE container, you need to configure the object. At the very least I appears you will need to call `setUrl()`, `setUser()` and `setPassword()`